# What is the domain of convergence of this power series: $\sum_\limits{n>1}{\frac{n^n}{n!}x^n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is the domain of convergence of this power series: $$\sum_{n>1}{\frac{n^n}{n!}x^n}$$ This is what I did: so we know that $$\sum_{n>1}{\frac{1}{n!}}=e$$
This means that my seres is now $\sum_\limits{n>1}{(n^ne)x^n}$ ? If yes, how do I calculate his Radius?

Comment: Can you do Ratio Test? Because that works to find the domain of convergence. It has got something to do with $e's$

Comment: @imranfat I know that the domain has to be $(-1/e,1/e)$. If I do the ratio test I will get a limit that goes to infinity $\frac{e(n+1)^{n+1}}{en^n}$, but if the ratio test is infinity than Radius is 0..

Comment: Yes, I got that too! Radius is then $1/e$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion in the last line of your question, where you say that your series is now $\sum_n(n^ne)x^n$. This new series, whose radius of convergence is clearly zero, is very different from your original series, and I don't see how you got from the one to the other.

As for the original series, the ratio test will give you the answer. The ratio of consecutive coefficients is
$$
\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}\cdot n!}{(n+1)!\cdot n^n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)\cdot n^n}
=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n,
$$
which converges to $e$ as $n\to\infty$. So the radiius of convergence is $1/e$.

Comment: I finaly understood what I was doing wrong, thx for everything.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Remember the radius of convergence of $\sum a_nx^n$ is given by

$$r=\frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}}$$

when the limit exists. Can you find the limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the radius of convergence either using the Root Test or the Ratio Test.

In the case of the Root Test, note that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}.
$$
Proof
$$
\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\big(\ln 1+\ln 2+\cdots+\ln n\big)-\ln n\\ =\frac{1}{n}\left(\ln \Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)+\ln \Big(\frac{2}{n}\Big)+\cdots+\ln \Big(\frac{n}{n}\Big)\right)\longrightarrow \int_0^1 \ln x\,dx=-1.
$$
Hence $\,\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\to\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}$.

Comment: I got this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$, but can you be more specific why $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}$?

Comment: @NeacsuMihai See my edited answer.